# Why not get notifications from my server to an iOS device using laravel, phonegap and APNs? stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto

Tags: php, ios, cordova, laravel-4, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send notifications from my host hosted at **GoDaddy** to iOS devices and do not work.

The tool to send notifications which I'm using is 
[Laravel package to enable sending push notifications to devices](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification)
Laravel version I use is 4.2 and the service is APNs.

The code I use to send the notification is:

```
$reg = Input::get('reg_id');
      if($reg != ""){
            $valor = PushNotification::Message('¡Tu pedido ha llegado!',array(
                'valor' => 2,
                'sound' => 'example.aiff',
             'actionLocKey' => 'Action button title!',
'locKey' => 'localized key',
'locArgs' => array(
    'localized args',
    'localized args',
),
'launchImage' => 'image.jpg',

'custom' => array('custom data' => array(
    'we' => 'want', 'send to app'
)) ));
            PushNotification::app('nameapp')
            ->to($reg)
            ->send($valor);
        }
```

And the settings I use is:

```
 return array(
    'nameapp'  => array(
    'environment' =>'development',
    'certificate' =>app_path() .'/cert/cert.pem',
    'passPhrase'  =>'password',
    'service'     =>'apns'
));
```

When I try to send the notification throws me the following error: **stream_socket_client (): Failed to enable crypto**

In the mobile application I'm using Phonegap with the plugin: **phonegap-plugin-push**

As extra information, I have no SSL certificate installed on my server and when I try to **TELNET** to the service **APNs** throws me the following:

```
 telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
 Trying 17.172.232.21...
 Connected to gateway.push.apple.com.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Thanks for your answers.